# List selection does not disappear after the second tap

Tags: android, listview, touch, selection, tap

I have a ListView or PreferenceView with some items (5 for ex.)
and each element has `android:background` value

```
android:background="@drawable/red_selector_list"
```

red_selector_list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_gradient" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_gradient" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red_gradient" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gray_gradient_list" />
</selector>
```

red_gradient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient 
        android:angle="90" 
        android:startColor="#990000"
        android:centerColor="#b00000" 
        android:endColor="#ff0000" 
        android:type="linear" />
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

gray_gradient_list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:angle="90" android:startColor="#ebebeb"
        android:endColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />
    <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Steps to reproduce this issue:

1. List item
2. Touch and hold any item
3. Touch and hold any **other** item using other finger
4. Remove finger which keeps option from step 2
5. Continue keep your finger from step 3 on the screen and swipe down until the
   end of screen

Highlighting always remains after selecting two items at the same time and should be disappeared. This issue cannot be reproduced with items without the `android:background` value. Could it be an Android platform issue?